# Ionic capacitor android app icon doesn't change

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

In my app I've changed all the image in the generated folder android\app\src\main\res\mipmap[...] with my app icon, but still I get the default image.
How is this possible?
The default image is not present anywhere....

Someone could give me some help?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned how you change the icon in android, I can only suggest you try what I tried successful way.

Using the cordova-res plugin to generate the plugin, and using scripts below to copy them into IOS or Android folders.

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons

Detail steps:

https://gist.github.com/dalezak/a6b1de39091f4ace220695d72717ac71

Comment: You re right. I found that on my phone and my launcher, the icon change does not works with custom items pack installed.